# How to get "double.class" by a "Double" Object

Tags: java, reflection

#### description:

- I need use `getMethod`, it requires the parameterTypes.
- The origin method requires `double` (a primitive type, not `Double`), and I can't change origin method.
- I can't just input `double.class` in parameterTypes, because the `s` maybe diffierent types, such as `Integer`(not `int`).
- The method parameter in `Foo.java` are always and only primitive types.

#### code:

```
test.java
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        Object obj = new Foo();
        Object s = 1.2;
        String type = "Double";
        try {
            Method method = obj.getClass().getMethod("return" + type, s.getClass());// got NoSuchMethodException here, because it requires `double` not Double
            System.out.println(method.invoke(obj,s));
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException |InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
Foo.java //(I can't change/add code/delete in this part)
public class Foo {
    public double returnDouble(double type){
        return type;
    }
    public int returnInt(int type){
        return type;
    }
}
```

#### what I have tried:

- Use Map

```
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        Object obj = new Foo();
//        Object s = 1;
//        String type = "Int";
        Object s = 1.2;
        String type = "Double";
        Map<String, Class> methodClassMap = new HashMap<String, Class>() {{
            put("Double",double.class);
            put("Integer",int.class);
        }};
        try {
            Method method = obj.getClass().getMethod("return" + type, methodClassMap.get(s.getClass().getSimpleName()));
            System.out.println(method.invoke(obj,s));
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException |InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

- It worked, but I have to list all possible type of value the `s`.

#### question:

- Any better solution than using Map? Maybe use generic?

Comment: What if there are two methods, one taking `Double` and the other taking `double`?

Comment: @Holger sorry I can't add or change the code of `Foo.java`. In real enviroment `Foo.java` is a part of auto-generated SDK.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question. What is your code supposed to do when there are both methods?

Comment: @Holger Do you mean there are both methods one taking `Double` and the other taking `double` in `Foo.java`? I don't have this problem so far.

Comment: You described a problem of handling an arbitrary object type (“I can't just input double.class in parameterTypes, because the s maybe diffierent type”). If you can’t rely on a particular type for the object or method parameter, how can you be sure, just assuming the method type to always be primitive will work reliably? Just because you didn’t “have this problem so far”? You have to be more specific about what you can reliably assume and which scenarios you have to handle.

Comment: @Holger Because I'm using `thirft` to generate SDK, it always and only use primitive type in method parameter. Sorry I think `thrift` is irrelevant to this problem so I didn't specific it.

Comment: It’s ok to omit the name. But the information that it will always be a primitive type, is helpful.

Comment: @Holger Anyway, thanks for informing `primitive`, I check it has only 8 types, and each one got a specific non-primitive type. Maybe use `map` is a proper solution. Thanks for helping me again.

Comment: 'I can't just input `double.class` in `parameterTypes`: yes you can. 'Because the s maybe diffierent types, such as Integer(not int).' This does not make sense.

Comment: @user207421 If I input `double.class` in `parameterTypes`, I need copy-paste the code several times for every possible type of `s`, use `switch` to arange them. Or maybe I miss something that can use `double.class` without a lot duplicated code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you know beforehand that the target method always uses a primitive types, you can use the [`unwrap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodType.html#unwrap()) method of `MethodType` of the `java.lang.invoke` package.

```java
Object obj = new Foo();
Object s = 1.2;
String type = "Double";
try {
    MethodType mt = MethodType.methodType(s.getClass(), s.getClass()).unwrap();
    Method method = obj.getClass().getMethod("return" + type, mt.parameterArray());
    System.out.println(method.invoke(obj, s));
} catch(ReflectiveOperationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Alternatively, when you’re already using the method type of the `java.lang.invoke` package, you can also use a method handle to perform the invocation.

```java
Object obj = new Foo();
Object s = 1.2;
String type = "Double";
try {
    MethodType mt = MethodType.methodType(s.getClass(), s.getClass()).unwrap();
    MethodHandle mh = MethodHandles.lookup().bind(obj, "return" + type, mt);
    System.out.println(mh.invoke(s));
} catch(Throwable e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But note that unlike Reflection, the return type has to be correctly specified for the lookup. I’m assuming the same return type as the parameter type, like in your example.